# UIKit: What happens when I have a UIView.animate inside an animation block?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uiviewanimation

Often in swift, I may want to have a property that, when set generally animates. In other words

```swift
class SelectableView: UIView {
   var isSelected: Bool = false {
      willSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.200) {
           self.backgroundColor = .red
        }
      }
   }
}
```

However, I am realizing that it may not be the best practice. For example, when I use my class elsewhere, I may accidentally do something like:

```
let k = SelectableView()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.500) {
   k.isSelected = true
   k.alpha = 1.0
   k.backgroundColor = .red // notice this!
}
```

In that event, what even occurs? What exactly is the behavior there? Does the color go to red in 500 milliseconds or 200 milliseconds? Does `willSet` matter versus `didSet`? What happens if I straight up nested the `UIView.animate` inline rather in the setter?

In general, is it perhaps a bad practice to have an animation block in the setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the setter you can check the value of `UIView.inheritedAnimationDuration`. If it’s 0, use default duration (i.e. 0.2). If it’s >0, use that value. Also, alternatively, if inherited duration is >0, you can skip animation in the setter, and just directly assign the value.

```
class SelectableView: UIView {
   var isSelected: Bool = false {
      didSet {
        let duration = UIView.inheritedAnimationDuration
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration > 0 ? duration : 0.200) {
           self.backgroundColor = .red
        }
      }
   }
}
```

In terms of good practices, Apple uses two setters in such cases:

- `isSelected` - no implicit animation
- `setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` - opted-in animation

The first one can be dynamic and call the second one with `animated: false` argument.

Comment: @WinstonDu don't you mind accepting it? :)

Answer (score 0):

The normal practice is to use duration `0`. This means that if you are in an animation block you will inherit the duration from that animation block.

So in your example, if the `isSelected` setter observer's animation duration is `0`, the call to set `isSelected` in the animation block will be animated with duration `0.5`.

Also, I would suggest using `didSet` rather than `willSet` (not for any particular reason, it's just what I do).

Comment: Right, but what if I want the property to animate with a default duration if not in an animation block?

Comment: I would use layer level animation to arrange that, so I really don’t know.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to solve the issue of an inner animation block or nested animation block to respect the given duration just use the option `overrideInheritedDuration`.

Swift 5 code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { // outer or even parent animation
   // inside some child
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, delay: 0, options: [.overrideInheritedDuration]) { 
       // your animation now uses the 4 seconds duration
       someView.animateProperty.value = 1
   }
}
```

For those of you coming from `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`/ `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot` bare in mind that when you use `yourViewController.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences::_)`. The animating differences if true wraps your cell changes in an animation block and is false it wraps your changes in a `UIView.performWithoutAnimation`.

That above means that if when you populate your cell you do some animations if you don't use that option `overrideInheritedDuration` your animations will be executed with the duration that iOS SDK send while you did your `snapshot.apply`.

It means as well that if in your cell setup you where settings a state pre animation and then an animation block, you won't have an animation at all!